# Did this character die?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In S01E02 of *Star Trek: Discovery*,

> Klingons rammed a cloaked ship into the USS Europa which had Starfleet Admiral on-board. The USS Europa was soon put to self destruct and we also saw several escape pods launching out of it. Did the Admiral die?

I know that the TV show didn't show further details, but do we have other sources saying whether or not he would appear on the show again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although we won't know for sure until future episodes air, it's worth remarking that the official [StarTrek.com database](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/admiralanderson) claims that he died:

> Starfleet Admiral at the Battle at the Binary Stars. He was killed when a Klingon cleeve ship attacked the *U.S.S. Europa.*

However, being dead doesn't mean he won't appear in future episodes; *Discovery* has already demonstrated that it isn't afraid of flashback scenes, for example.

Comment: Your last sentence invalidates my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to cite another popular show at the moment: "This Is Us" as evidence that a character need not be alive in one time period to appear in the show

Answer (score -2):

## I believe, No

Reasoning:

> According to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5171438/fullcredits?mode=desktop&ref_=m_ft_dsk), Terry Serpico has been signed for 13 episodes to play Admiral Anderson.

It means, he survived.

Comment: Unfortunately, those figures on IMDb don't have anything to do with whether an actor has signed any contract. They just show the number of episodes as entered by an IMDb editor with appropriate permissions; think wikipedia. So the only information is really "Terry Serpico ... 
 Admiral Anderson / ... (13 episodes, 2017-2018)" but since only 2 episodes have been seen, that number is really meaningless. (Personally I think it'd be unprecedented to survive what happened.)

Comment: @MarkBeadles But, next to some actors, episode numbers are 3, 2 etc. I don't think these are random numbers entered by someone.

Comment: Note that Jason Isaacs is *also* listed for 15 episodes, and he doesn't even appear in the first 2. The numbers aren't random, they're just inaccurate because the episodes haven't aired yet and the numbers haven't been cleared up.